# How to get value from Input type="number", and provide it to value attribute of other input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to edit my table row. When I'm trying to edit it, the previous value isn't getting update to new input box.I want to get the number in the new input box. I tried passing `value="' + $(this).text() + '">'` but it work for `type="text"`, whereas it doesn't work for type="number". Can anyone please help.

```
// Edit row on edit button click
$(document).on("click", ".edit", function(){        
    $(this).parents("tr").find("td:not(:last-child, :nth-last-child(2))").each(function(){
        $(this).html('<input type="text" class="heading_label-box" value="' + $(this).text() + '">');
    });  
    $(this).parents("tr").find("td:nth-last-child(3)").each(function(){
        $(this).html('<input type="number" class="heading_total-weight" value="' + $(this).text() + '">');
    });    
    $(this).parents("tr").find(".add, .edit").toggle();
    $(".add-heading, .add-point").attr("disabled", "disabled");
});
```

I have tried `$(this).val()`, `$(this).value()`, but cant get the value.

Comment: Could you also add your html?

Comment: `.parents("tr")` Is it nested multiple rows? closest() would be probably better.

Answer (score 0):

Since the object you want to update with the input is a TD, you should do this instead:

```
$(document).on("click", ".edit", function(){        
    $(this).parents("tr").find("td:not(:last-child, :nth-last-child(2))").each(function(){
        let thisVal = $(this).text();
        let inputObj = $('<input type="text" class="heading_label-box"/>');
        inputObj.val(thisVal);
        $(this).html('');
        $(this).append(inputObj);
    });  
    $(this).parents("tr").find("td:nth-last-child(3)").each(function(){
        let thisVal = $(this).text();
        let inputObj = $('<input type="number" class="heading_total-weight"/>');
        inputObj.val(thisVal);
        $(this).html('');
        $(this).append(inputObj);
    });    
    $(this).parents("tr").find(".add, .edit").toggle();
    $(".add-heading, .add-point").attr("disabled", "disabled");
});
```

Comment: While inspecting, thisVal is empty, it shows `thisVal = " " `

Comment: If is empty then the content on the TD is empty too. Please check your selector to see if it's the right TD.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that input with type number does not work.

```js
$(this).html('<input type="number" class="heading_total-weight" value="' + $(this).text() + '">');
```

.text() returns String, thus it does not work.